# Gson ignores custom @SerializedName values for enum on serialization

Tags: android, kotlin, gson, retrofit2

I have enums like this:

```
enum class NewTaskState(val value: Int) {

    @SerializedName("0")
    STATE_INSTALLED(0),

    @SerializedName("1")
    STATE_LAUNCHED(1)

}
```

API call with retrofit:

```
 @POST("tasks/android/{id}/state/update/")
 @FormUrlEncoded
 fun updateAppTaskState(
     @Path("id") id: Long,
     @Query("device_pk") deviceId: Long,
     @Field("new_state") newState: NewTaskState
 ): Single<Response<Any>>
```

And GSON configuration:

```
return GsonBuilder()
    .registerTypeAdapter(Date::class.java, DateDeserializer())
    .enableComplexMapKeySerialization()
    .create()
```

Gson version is `2.8.5`.

When I use this call, I see in logs:

```
I/OkHttp: --> POST <removed>/tasks/android/1/state/update/?device_pk=8
I/OkHttp: Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
I/OkHttp: Content-Length: 25
I/OkHttp: Authorization: Token <removed>
I/OkHttp: new_state=STATE_INSTALLED
```

So it ignores `@SerializedName` value on **serialization**, but works fine on **deserialization**.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because `Gson` does not participate in url form-encoding.

From [`@Field`](https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/http/Field.html)'s javadoc:

> **Values are converted to strings using `Retrofit.stringConverter(Type, Annotation[])` (or`Object.toString()`, if no matching string converter is installed)** and then form URL encoded. `null` values are ignored. Passing a `List` or array will result in a field pair for each non-`null` item.

And [`GsonConverterFactory`](https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/master/retrofit-converters/gson/src/main/java/retrofit2/converter/gson/GsonConverterFactory.java) does not override [`Converter.Factory#stringConverter`](https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/Converter.Factory.html#stringConverter-java.lang.reflect.Type-java.lang.annotation.Annotation:A-retrofit2.Retrofit-) so it is not ignoring anything. It's merely not kicking in

---

As a workaround you can do something similar:

**`Converter`**:

```
object EnumAsOrdinalToStringConverter : Converter<Enum<*>, String> {
    override fun convert(value: Enum<*>): String =
            value.ordinal.toString()
}
```

**`Factory`**:

```
class EnumAsOrdinalToStringConverterFactory : Converter.Factory() {
    override fun stringConverter(
            type: Type,
            annotations: Array<Annotation>,
            retrofit: Retrofit
    ): Converter<*, String>? = if (type is Class<*> && type.isEnum) {
        EnumAsOrdinalToStringConverter
    } else {
        null
    }
}
```

**Building `Retrofit`**:

```
addConverterFactory(EnumAsOrdinalToStringConverterFactory())
```